# Why the data result returned blank when querying different time series using * in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I can find the data separately for different time series using `select sum(size) from root.ad.invert where tenant="tenant_1"`, and `select sum(size) from root.ldh.invert where tenant="tenant_1"`. However, when I use `select sum(size) from root.*.invert where tenant="tenant_1"` to try to query the two time series together, I can't find any data results. What's the reason for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe because the data of the two Apache IoTDB databases are not aligned and the timestamps are inconsistent. Try to set the time series to aligned and see if you can query them together.